# Menu dropdown abre parcialmente

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um menu dropdown utilizando twitter-bootstrap 3 e ele esta dentro de uma `<li class="media">`, então cada `<li>` tem um dropdown com algumas ações, acontece que quando como a altura da `<li>` é menor que a altura do menu ele não mostra todas as opções alguém sabe como resolver?

Exemplo no jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cx6qa617/

Comment: Uma coisa para poder tentar ajudar: no "aqui vai normal" você só coloca o conjunto ul.dropdown-menu?

Comment: tu diz trocar de lugar?

Comment: Não, perguntei qual a mudança que você faz e acaba funcionando.

Comment: Não, ali é um comentário do sistema... nada a ver com o problema, até vou editar o código

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ola.

Fiz uns testes aqui.
Você deve adicionar a opção `<li style='overflow:visible;'`, ficará assim: `<li class="media" style="overflow:visible;border-bottom: solid 1px; margin-bottom: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; " id="comment_71">`.

Na `<div class="media-body">`, troque por `<div class="panel-body">` que irá funcionar.

Vlw

Comment: Era isso mesmo, obrigado.

Comment: Certo, sempre as ordens! Abraços

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que a `<li class="media">` está com `overflow:hidden;`, adicionei `style='overflow:visible;'` e apareceu o dropdown.

Comment: Ficou a mesma coisa.

Comment: coloquei e funcionou, veja: http://jsfiddle.net/cx6qa617/9/

Comment: @DanielLemes é no elementro `<li>` e não na `<div>`, corrigi.

Comment: Achei estranho porque a sua solução funcionava online e aqui não funcionou, foi quando vi a resposta do @Gilvan Andre percebi que você tirou a class da primeira div e assim ficou funcionando.

Answer (score 1):

Não conheço nada de bootstrap, mas fiquei bem interessado...

O caminho parece ser por aqui:

**CSS:**

```
.dropdown-menu{
    position:fixed;
}
```

**jquery:**

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function (){
            dropDownFixPosition($(this),$(this).next('.dropdown-menu'));
        });
function dropDownFixPosition(button,dropdown){
      var dropDownTop = button.offset().top + button.outerHeight();
        dropdown.css('top', dropDownTop + "px");
        dropdown.css('left', button.offset().left + "px");
}
```

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/cx6qa617/3/

**fonte:** https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/7160

---

Verifique possíveis incompatibilidades em browsers diferentes:

**IE 11:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Firefox:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

z-index não funcionou?

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="z-index:99999">
                <li><a href="#">Ação 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ação 2</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ação 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ação 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ação 5</a></li>
            </ul>
```

ou

```
<style>
    li { z-index:-1; }
</style>
```

Comment: Não funcionou, tentei das duas maneiras